# Click on arrow changes content of 5 buttons by +1 value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="container_p pull-right" id="container_p">
<button type="button" class="btn_p pull-right" id="naglowek_p_zwiniety">P</button>
<div class="btn-group-vertical pull-right hide" role="group" id="grupa_p">

  <button type="button" class="btn_strzalka btn_strzalka_gora_p border_top" id="strzalka_gora_p">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn_litery_p btn_wspolne border_bottom" value="0" id="p0">0</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn_litery_p btn_wspolne border_bottom" value="1" id="p1">1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn_litery_p btn_wspolne border_bottom" value="2" id="p2">2</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn_litery_p btn_wspolne border_bottom" value="3" id="p3">3</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn_litery_p btn_wspolne" value="4" id="p4">4</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn_litery_p btn_wspolne" value="5" id="p5">5</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn_strzalka btn_strzalka_dol_p border_top"  id="strzalka_dol_p">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn_p_top btn_p" id="naglowek_p">P</button>
</div>
</div>
```

And this JS script:

```
var liczba_p = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12'];
var liczba_przyciskow = ['0','1','2','3','4','5'];
  var licz = 0;
  var liczenie = 0;
  var j = 0;
   $('#strzalka_gora_p').click(function(){
     for (var i = 0; i<liczba_p.length;i++)
     {
      if (j == liczba_przyciskow.length)
      {
        j=0;
      }
      licz = licz+1;
      if (licz == liczba_p.length)
      {
       licz = licz -1;   
       document.getElementById('strzalka_gora_p').disabled=true;
      }

 document.getElementById("p"+liczba_przyciskow[j]).innerHTML=liczba_p[licz];
         j++;
     }

document.getElementById("p"+liczba_przyciskow[liczenie]).innerHTML = licz+1;
  })

 $('#strzalka_dol_p').click(function(){
   for (var i =0; i<liczba_przyciskow.length;i++){
   if (i==liczba_przyciskow.length){i=0;}else{
     licznik = Number(licznik)-1;
     tab_licznik_p[i]=licznik;
     document.getElementById("p"+liczba_przyciskow[i]).innerHTML = tab_licznik_p[i];
     document.getElementById("p"+liczba_przyciskow[i]).value = tab_licznik_p[i];
   }
   }
})
```

Now it works that when i click the arrow-up, the values change from:
0|1|2|3|4|5 to 1|2|3|4|5|6 but after another click they change to 7|8|9|10|11|12. 
How should i write JS so click of arrow up would add +1 every time i click and after first click i would get: 1|2|3|4|5|6 and after another click |2|3|4|5|6|7 etc. 
Number of buttons on site is always 5

Comment: Is this real variable names that you will use in prod?

Comment: can you provide a js fiddle for this? It would be easy to debug? With this kind of variable naming its really hard to understand the flow

Comment: Is this entire lot of code necessary for the question? @HarkiratSaluja , me, and many other stackoverflow users will disregard this question and never answer it, because you made it too difficult to answer with all of the "extra" code

Comment: @DaMaxContent extra code? Indentation was messed up just made it proper. I did not add anything new

Comment: "extra" meaning unneccessary. People need to see your problem outlined. It is a bad strategy to pose us with a complex program to ask a simple question. Simplify your program to OUTLINE what you need.

Comment: It gets you answers much faster

Comment: sorry, i thought if i put the whole code which i wrote for this behaviour it would be better. As for JSFiddle, i did not know this, i am truly sorry, in future i will use it. The naming of the variables is what i use, it is in polish - as wrote before i will try to use more global variables next time - please be patient with me. Thank you for the answer and additional comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Try JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/harishkommuri/zVzD6/132/)

```
$('#strzalka_gora_p').click(function() {
 var firstBtnVal = Number($('#grupa_p button[value="0"]').text());
 if (firstBtnVal >= 1) {
   for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
     var btnVal = Number($('#grupa_p button[value="' + i + '"]').text());
     $('#grupa_p button[value="' + i + '"]').text(btnVal - 1);
   }
 }
});

$('#strzalka_dol_p').click(function() {
  var lastBtnVal = Number($('#grupa_p button[value="5"]').text());
  if (lastBtnVal < 12) {
   for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
     var btnVal = Number($('#grupa_p button[value="' + i + '"]').text());
     $('#grupa_p button[value="' + i + '"]').text(btnVal + 1);
   }
 }
});
```